# ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied Oracle 12c - release 12.2.0.1.0

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, ora-01017

I have a problem sometimes with connecting to DB with Oracle 12c 12.2. When DBA changes my password, to the same password the connection is back.

We add some lines to the server into sqlora.net:

```
SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION_CLIENT=8
SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION_SERVER=8
```

but with any luck. Still the same issues. Can you get any suggestions?

I have Oracle client 11 and use sql developer. Thanks for helping.

Comment: You say that the DBA is changing your password to the same password.  Oracle seems to be telling a different story.  I would tend to believe Oracle and suspect that your password is getting changed.

Comment: @Nevis Perhaps those sqlnet.ora changes have not fully taken effect yet for all users. Changes to that file may require restarting the listener or even the entire database. Since DBAs often connect to a database differently than normal users, perhaps the settings are only applied to your DBA. To find out more information, use this query after you and the DBA change your password: `select name, spare4 from sys.user$ where name = 'YOUR_USERNAME';`  If the SPARE4 column contains different kinds of password hashes, that implies the settings aren't applied properly.

Comment: JustinCave & JonHeller for help. I will check and return with feedback.